# Royden Chapter 6

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm really stuck on this question.  Any help would be appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: Where are you blocked ?

Comment: What is $D_{1 \over n} f$?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, I believe we use the definition: discrete formulation of the F.T.C $\int_a^b Diff_h f=Av_hf(b)-Av_hf(a)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think $D_{1/n} f(x)=\frac {f(x+\frac  1n) -f(x)} {1/n}$. For the proof you only have to handle RHS. Write $\int_a^{b}  \frac {f(x+\frac  1n) -f(x)} {1/n}$ as $n\int_b^{b+1/n} f(x) dx-n\int_a^{a+1/n} f(x) dx$ and note that this tends to $f(b)-f(a)$ by continuity.